# How to debug PHP in the MAMP?

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

I'm using MAMP on Windows to start a web server for my WordPress website. I want to debug some PHP code (at least write variable values to log/browser console/anywhere else). I've tried to write in PHP source this:

```
debug_to_console($args);
var_dump($args);
error_log(print_r($args,true));
```

And looked for the result in MAMP/logs/phperror.log. But it doesn't write anything.

How to debug PHP code in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to debug WordPress, just turn on [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). Add this into your `wp-config` file instead of this one `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );`

Add this code:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

Next step is just using this one:

```
error_log(print_r($args,true));
```

Your `$args` you'll see in the `{your-local-website-path}/wp-content/debug.log` file

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work.$test = 'a';
error_log(print_r($test,true));