# WordPress media having various issues

Tags: wordpress, image-processing, media, image-uploading

I have been facing these issues for a while now. Searched a lot, but couldn't find anything that is similar or correspondent to all these issues.

- On media upload, it shows `HTTP error`
- Some images are getting uploaded and some are not. Uploaded ones are of different types and sizes. So, not sure what's getting rejected.
- Images are not being cropped, and showing error
- Uploaded images via `FTP`, but it doesn't appear in the library.
- 2 types of `HTTP error` recorded, one `GET` from one of the two media folders. And `POST`on cropping, uploading or linking any external image.

I would think it's some memory issue, but tried with images removing and uploading, but nothing. Also, the cropping error is making sense otherwise. Couldn't find any thread where someone might have faced the same, so I am clueless at this point.

Comment: we can't guess why is you're getting errors your mentioned. provide more details, such as console errors. error logs.

Comment: `Uploaded images via FTP, but it doesn't appear in the library.` : and even if all will work correct, you'll not see them in the Media Library, just because the files from library loads from db only( if there are columns related to some file, only after it WordPress loading them in the library ),

Comment: Ok, I just checked and there's a lot of 404 errors about not finding many media files, of which the placeholders are also white in the media library.
Doesn't seem like a permission issue. All images are on 644

Comment: it's console errors, right? just 404 errors?

Comment: yes, console errors.

Comment: any errors besides 404? does urls looks different from your other exists image urls?

Comment: No other errors. And the URLs, It seems like they're missing from a folder `2017` and the only images loading are from `2018` . Somehitng like this - http://www.example.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/home-4-225x300.jpg

Comment: but are they missing? also, did you enable [debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48905999/8053001)? any errors?

Comment: Nope, the files are there.

Comment: No errors from debug mode. Only the console errors. And one particular plugin error which I have faced before and everything has been working fine with it. e.g. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/post-grid/grid-items/variables.php on line 114
I have tried with deactivating the plugin, but nothing.

Comment: Just to confirm, I should see some errors in the Admin Panel on loading the Media Library or any other page which are showing the console errors right?

Comment: you can;t upload image from Media Library, right? if so then you should get them in the Library page, if they exists. what `HTTP error` your getting on image upload?

Comment: I can only upload some, but not all. I haven't figured out what type are getting uploaded.
And the http error - `POST http://www.example.com/dev/wp-admin/async-upload.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: try to get that error one more time with enabled debug mode, and after check debug log. provide new ones, if they appeared

Comment: It's the same, nothing additional. Also, the site isn't letting me post any images from links even. If that helps understanding anything.
So far, I can see 2 HTTP errors `GET` and `POST` ,  I am guessing it's just not one issue.

Comment: update your question with all errors you're getting

Comment: Unfortunately, my client didn't have enough time and cancelled the order and blocked my access to the WordPress, so I was unable to update much. But updated the question as much as I remember, so if someone gets a solution or has the same issue can get something from it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to upload content from abroad (not from country where your hosting provider is located)? If you do, you have to add the country you are trying to upload from to the exemptions in your hosting control panel.

I had the exact same problem and that solved the issue for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I lost access to the WordPress and wasn't able to fix it. But if I come across this again, I will definitely try this solution and update here if it worked.