# Cannot var_dump or echo variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this function that modifies shipping methods according to weight.

I need to var_dump or echo $rates in order to access & condition certain properties of it (like cost which you can see).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'compoco_wholesale_rates', 10 );
function compoco_wholesale_rates( $rates ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $base_cost = 0;
    $cart_weight = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();

    $shipping_price = array('3' => 34, '4' => 42, '5' => 50, '6' => 58, '7' => 66, '8' => 73, '9' => 80, '10' => 88, '11' => 95, '12' => 102, '13' => 107, '14' => 117, '15' => 125, '16' => 132, '17' => 140, '18' => 146, '19' => 153, '20' => 163);
    foreach ( $shipping_price as $key => $value){

        if( round($cart_weight) == $key){
            $base_cost = $value;
        }
    }

    foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {

        $rate->cost = $base_cost;
    }
        return $rates;
}
```

Nothing happens when trying to output the var in question.

Comment: Have you tried 'print_r()' ?

Comment: Can u try it ??
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rates);
exit;

I think it will work.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your filter running? Are you sure? What do you mean "nothing happens" - that means there's FAR too many potential issues to go into.  First, prove the filter runs (put an `echo 'PROOF'; die();` inside of it, at the very top, before ANY if statements, etc).

Comment: I put a print_r just now in the second foreach, nothing. Replaced return $rates with the the echo <pre> and exit, nothing. The filter is running because I am getting the correct $rate->cost from $base_cost of the first foreach.

Comment: if you need it for debug, follow [this steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48905999/8053001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($rates); die;
```

inside the function.

If this is a backend or something unaccessible from any screen you could create a file and put the var content inside (true flag in print_r).

```
$h = fopen('/var/www/whatever/rates.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($h, print_r($rates, true));
    fclose($h);
```

Keep in mind you can use https://xdebug.org/ in order to solve that kind of issues.

Comment: The thing is I got it to output in some kind of way but I can't recreate it, so I guess it can be solved within these lines. All I can recall for certain is removing the return statement.

Comment: This added to the start of the function + It appears that the variable value of $rates can be returned as a response to wc_refreshed _fragments when recalculating the shipping rate.